# Why these line of script does not move upload image file into desire directory?

Tags: php, file-upload, form-submit

Well I am trying to upload image into the blog/upload/. and the script location is in admin_panel/add_post.php.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['save'])){

$image = $_FILES['img']['name'];
$target_dir = "../blog/upload";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img']['tmp_name'],$target_file);

//get rid of all database operation and connection

}  
?>

<form action="add_posts.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="img"><span class='name'>Select Image:</span></label>
<input type="file" class="form-control" name="img" id="img" 
placeholder="Image">
</div>
```

Here is my url:

```
 localhost/sensive_blog/admin_panel/add_posts.php
```

My project folder hierarchy:

```
admin_panel
 ->otherScript.php
 ->somefolder
 ->add_post.php
blog
 ->someotherscripts.php
 ->folder
```

Comment: Where is it putting it? Checked your error logs / seeing any notices / warnings etc?

Comment: Check for file permissions error. Is your error reporting enabled?

Comment: does the upload folder exist?

Comment: @Jonnix i have declared the error_reporting(1). it does not show me any erros by right click on view page source.

Comment: @Jah yes bro it exits.

Comment: @seekingKnowledge - whats the read write permission of the folder?

Comment: join this room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190431/upload-issue

Comment: @Jah i have less reputation thats why i can join chat room. I am runnig my webapp in windows operating system. i read  about files/folder permission in linux envirnoment now i don't know how to find the permission status of directories in my project directory.

Comment: join here: https://y99.in/r/34453 / 12345

Answer (score 0):

add this after **$target_dir**, to check if folder exist

```
if (!is_dir($target_dir)) {
    die('path not found);
}
```

Comment: It did not stop my script.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my mistake. Basically it was uploading image but at wrong `directory` which is blog with weird name `"upload[image_name]"`. so Then I put one forward slash `/` to go to right `directory`. and then magic did happen.